# How to send inbox messages with facebook sdk php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I would like to send a private message to inbox, like:

```
$facebook->api('/me/feed','POST',array(
'message'=>'mensagem aqui',
'name'=>'nome aqui',
'caption'=>'caption aqui',
));
```

but send it to inbox.

it's possible do to?

I mean it:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. See [Facebook Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) and [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) (scroll down to Publishing section).

If the user has a facebook email (like user@facebook.com) you can just send an email there. Another alternative is to do a 'private' post. See [Graph API Post](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/)